# Cordova: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Camera

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm working on an App to collect technical issues. For each issue it's possible to upload 6 images to the server. Not the problem is as follows:

After starting the app, I'm opening one issue (can be no. one, no. 4 or no. 5) and navigate to the Photos-Page. Now I can start the camera or start the gallery (per button) to select a photo from. This works perfectly for one, two or even three or four photos.

Now, when I'm navigating back to the issues list, open another issue and navigating to Photos-Page, I try to press the "Select from Gallery" or the "Camera"-Button. On pressing the camera button, I'm able to create an new photo with the camera app, but on committing the photo, I only get an alert: "Camera cancelled.". Same with selecting an image from the gallery: I press the button and before the selection window opens, I'm getting an alert "Selection cancelled.". After this most of the JavaScript is not working anymore. I can not navigate back to the issues list or even cant close the app from menu.

If I look to the error log, I'm getting a the following lines:

```
12-18 09:02:45.015 1748-1748/com.app.mosiris W/CordovaPlugin: Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Camera1583519487
12-18 09:02:45.015 1748-1748/com.app.mosiris W/CordovaPlugin: Result was: "Selection cancelled."
12-18 09:02:45.015 1748-1748/com.app.mosiris W/CordovaInterfaceImpl: Got an activity result, but no plugin was registered to receive it.
```

On pressing the "Select from gallery"-button, no image is even selected and I'm getting the alert "Selection cancelled."

So, as I understand:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(success, fail, {quality: 20, allowEdit: true, sourceType: src, destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL});
```

works perfect on first selected issue but on opening another issue it runs into fail function even if no file was selected.

Can anybody give me an idea or a hint to the right direction?

Thanx in advance!

PS: Cordova is 5.3.1 and also the Camera plugin is the latest code.

Answer (score 1):

Possible causes:
1. Depending on the device, the url-s you are getting might be trying to write to the same location and failing.
2. Low memory in your device
3. Cascading callbacks not handled correctly

If you post your code, it might be easier to help you. I recently came across this [Media plugin](http://market.ionic.io/plugins/onymos-media) at the Ionic market place that I am in such awe using it, that I will recommend you to take a look at it for issues as yours. That plugin provides for multiple 'callId'-s to be used to distinguish between each call that this second callback issue does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but will help future readers. Had this same issue.

Make sure you have set `pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true)`. This will internally set the value of `finished` in `org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext` class to `false`. Check [CallbackContext source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CallbackContext.java#L58).

`In Kotlin`

```
class TestPlugin: CordovaPlugin() {
    private var callbackContext : CallbackContext? = null
    private val ACTION_TEST = "test"

    override fun execute(action: String?, args: JSONArray?, callbackContext: CallbackContext?): Boolean {
        if (ACTION_TEST == action) {
            this.callbackContext = callbackContext
            val pluginResult = PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT)
            pluginResult.keepCallback = true
            this.callbackContext?.sendPluginResult(pluginResult)
            Log.d(TAG, "execute: init finished:${this.callbackContext?.isFinished}, id:${this.callbackContext?.callbackId}")
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun sendAnotherResult() {
         val arr = JSONArray()
         val pluginResult = PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, arr)
         pluginResult.keepCallback = true
         Log.d(TAG, "sendAnotherResult: finished:${callbackContext?.isFinished}, callbackid:${callbackContext?.callbackId}")
         callbackContext?.sendPluginResult(pluginResult)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaPlugin.java
```

Change `return false` to `true`:

```
public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

" Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Camera1583519487"
it is because you are in the same callback with the same callbackID.
you could change the callbackID,and you will execution the callback repeatly .
it is my code to sulution this problem(in my opinion：use different callbackID):

```
if (startCallbackContext != null) {
            PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, volume);
            if(isLastGloble == true){
                pluginResult.setKeepCallback(false);
            }
            else{
                pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
                webView.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, startCallbackContext.getCallbackId());

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));// new Date()为获取当前系统时间
                System.out.println("---------->>>"+"onVolumeChanged... "+volume+" ..."+startCallbackContext.getCallbackId());

                xxxxx.this.webView.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(
                        PluginResult.Status.OK, volume), df.format(new Date()));
            }
        }
```